# How to prevent voltage until a specific voltage is met?

Tags: resistors, diodes, voltage-regulator

I have a question that I have not been able to answer through hours of searching (or at least I don't believe I have found the answer.)

I'm trying to get a DC relay to trigger at a certain voltage but not before that threshold is met.

Here is the scenario:

The vehicle has an electronic throttle body and gas pedal. From just idling to full throttle, the throttle pedal reads 0.800v +- 0.050 (idle)  to 4.4V +- 0.050 (full throttle).

If I connect the relay to the throttle wire it will trigger it almost immediately once the car is on. I don't want to have the relay trigger to get voltage until around 3V to 3.5V.  How do I achieve blocking the voltage until that specific range?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are power management ICs that are specifically for this sort of thing, but I don't have time to do the research and write up an answer right now.

Comment: You could use an Arduino with an ADC, trigger a relay when the voltage level exceeds some set point. This way it's more precise and configurable.

Comment: @RonBeyer:  Or just use a comparator and a potentiometer.  I like programming as much as the next person, but sometimes it's better just to go simple.

Comment: You need to link to the relay's data sheet and also note that hanging a relay on the throttle wire may cause other problems without a buffer amplifier.

Comment: A simple comparator would do the job. You can't rely on the pickup voltage of the relay since it has a really wide tolerance. Also you are loading that signal line with the relay coil and that could give troubles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can throw together a few discretes and accomplish this:

D2 is a comparator + 2.5V reference (available in TO-92).
Q1 does the grunt work of switching the relay.
D3 protects Q1 against D3 inductance

The components in the dashed box add a few hundred mV of hysteresis to prevent
relay chattering. C1 also helps filter the input.

The thresholds are nominally about 3.4V to turn the relay "on" and 3.1V to turn it off.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVqXEf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You might want to add a 30-50V zener across Q1 (emitter to collector) to protect against transients on the 12V line.

The relay coil can be 100 ohms or more.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting a relay to a signal is a bad idea.  Besides not switching when you want to it, the coil is a heavy load to place on a signal wire.  As if that weren't bad enough, the relay could damage something in the throttle sensor or the engine control unit if you ever get the relay to switch at all.

What you'll need is a comparator.  A comparator compares two input voltages and switches its output when one is higher than the other.  It will draw next to no current from the throttle signal, and won't cause other problems for the ECU.

A simple comparator circuit would look something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH2Uyp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The [LM393](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm393-n.pdf) compares the "Throttle" voltage to the voltage set by R1.  If "Throttle" is higher than the set level, then the output goes high, switching current through the base of Q1.  The current through the collector of Q1 activates the relay.  D1 is there to protect Q1 from the high voltage that is generate when the relay coil is turned off later.

You'll need to make a small circuit board with a 5V regulator and the LM393 (and the other parts.)

---

I'm not sure if Ron Beyer was joking, but you could replace the LM393 with a properly programmed Arduino (or other microprocessor of your choice.)

I think that's kind of overkill just to translate a voltage into an on/off signal.

---

This is one of those projects where you need to ask yourself "Do I really need to do this?"

A short circuit on the wire from the throttle sensor to your circuit could cause your vehicle to do strange things - most likely the ECU would decide to shut down, but that's not a sure  thing.

This has the potential to get you in trouble - either at your next inspection, or in the investigation after a crash.

Think it over, and see if maybe there's another way to accomplish your task before you start attaching home grown circuits to the controls of your engine.